# How to operate times in python

Tags: python, pandas, time

I am very new to using python and now I need to add times in minutes. I mean, the data that the computer gives me is 10:23:12 , the first being the hours, then the minutes and finally the seconds. What I want to do is to have a cumulative time in minutes, that cell 1 is added with cell 2, and cell 2 with cell 2.

In excel i have this data

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 12/1/2022 | 3:51:52 |
| 12/1/2022 | 3:53:31 |
| 12/1/2022 | 3:55:11 |

And want to sum each cell.

I am using pandas to manipulate the data

I am expecting to obtain this

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/1/2022 | 3:51:52 | 51.87 | 0 |
| 12/1/2022 | 3:53:31 | 53.52 | 1.65 |
| 12/1/2022 | 3:55:11 | 55.18 | 3.32 |

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to directly operate with the time. Just transform the string and do the calculations you need, for example, like this:

```
n = '3:51:52'  # As an example. Substitute with your actual strings.
hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, n.split(':'))
# Effectively, the above line does something akin to this: 
# hours, minutes, seconds = n.split(':')
# hours = int(hours)
# minutes = int(minutes)
# seconds = int(seconds)

time_in_seconds = hours * 360 + minutes * 60 + seconds
time_in_minutes = hours * 60 + minutes + seconds / 60
```

Comment: What happens when the date increases?

Comment: @Axe319 Something like 1232:51:52 will still return the correct answer, because we are using split() using the colon, instead of depending on a format with digits. I'm not sure if this is what is bothering you.

Comment: Just that there's a date column ("Column A") in the question and python includes a `datetime` module that does that work for you. I'm assuming that since there's a date column, that "Column B" will always be a valid time (`00:00:01` - `23:59:59`) but that may not be the case, and this may be sufficient.